# How to select and select in same query?

Tags: mysql

i just want to know if this is possible i find some here at stackoverflow but i didnt understand distinct and other select(select) code

the tables

**tblproducts**

```
motherboard,       cpu,
Asus_board         intel
MSI_board          amd
```

where in this table they also have the same name

**compatibility**

```
motherboard,       form_factor,
Asus_board         ATX
MSI_board          AT
```

the query i have

```
$query = "Select from tblproducts where category = 'motherboard' AND Select from compatibilty where form_factor = 'ATX'";
```

i made different table to make motherboard compatibility, I really need the tblproducts because the table have the product images

the output i want will be filtered only those ATX form_factor will be output
thank you for your understanding not good at programming

output will be  Asus_board only because it has ATX form_factor

Comment: If you share your expected output then it useful to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: maybe i was bad at doing queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tblproducts.motherboard, tblproducts.cpu, compatibility.form_factor
FROM tblproducts, compatibility
WHERE compatibility.form_factor = 'ATX' 
AND tblproducts.motherboard = compatibility.motherboard
```

If you only want `tblproducts` columns, just remove any references to the `compatibility` table from the `SELECT` clause (but leave it in the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses).

Comment: Correct answer although for an inexperienced user like @Aze Ronquillo the Oracle style join may be a bit confusing!

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your help I try to understand this one i have experienced Oracle a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Simply join those table and give where condtion.

```
select a.motherboard from tblproducts a join compatibility b on (a.motherboard=b.motherboard)
where b.form_factor='ATX'
```

Comment: As long as `form_factor` is only on one of those tables; I would do `WHERE b.form_factor ...` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah I have edited it to avoid ambiguity.. thanks @Tim Lewis